# Rails TextHelper "highlight" method for case-insensitive search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails TextHelper "highlight" method for highlighting a search string.

```
<%= simple_format highlight("Some test text", "some") %>
```

However, it seems to be case-sensitive. Is there a case-insensitive version of this function? Or maybe some option i'm missing?

Comment: can you just downcase your args to bypass the case sensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

Du-oh!
It turns out,  Highlight method is already case insensitive.

I had a check before the line to see if the string includes the query text. I used the ruby .include? method for that which is not case sensitive!

```
<% if query && faq.answer.downcase.include?(query.downcase) %> 
  <%= highlight(excerpt(faq.answer, query, :radius => 100), query) %>
<% else %>
  <%= truncate(faq.answer, :length => 200) %> 
<% end %>
```

Using a downcase on the include? check made it work.